# Do redirect 301 for wordpress page

Tags: redirect

I have two domains, one server, the same files here and there. I want to redirect from one domain to another, but something does not work. What I write in .htaccess appears on both, as one server, the same files here and there. But the host does not have such a function and I need to through .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.ch/$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://old.ch/$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ https://new.ch/$1 [R=301,L]
```

it's work 50/50 and doesnt work in the incognito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
```

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]